# How to update data in a plot do create animations in octave

Tags: matlab, animation, plot, octave

I'm trying to plot a 2d array line by line each time in a loop with the pause command to create animations. I did this already in matlab and octave but I had the plot command inside the loop which for octave makes the whole thing slower. I saw somewhere I can just update the data in the plot, but for some reason it doesn't work. I'm I doing something wrong here?

say x is some constant array D=(1*m) and y a variable array D=(n*m). D -> dimensons

```
h=plot(x,y(:,1),'-');
while true
    for i=1:length(t)
        axis([0 l -A A]);
        hold on;
        set(h,'YData',y(:,i));
        pause(0.01)
        cla
    end

end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't need the `hold on` in your code. The following works fine in Octave 3.8.1 with fltk as the graphics toolkit:

```
t = linspace (0, 2*pi, 100);
y = sin (0.1*t);
h = plot (t, y);
for f = 0.2:0.1:2*pi
  y = sin (f*t);
  set (h, 'YData', y);
endfor
```

Comment: Ok thanks! It doesn't need the hold on but it needs the pause function. But it's still really slow in octave. It seems it keeps loading the figure for each i in the loop. (it's perfect in matlab)

Comment: @David there is no slowness in my system. The example I have on my reply takes exactly 0.126107 seconds (measure with tic/toc) on my system. Replacing `set (h, ...)` with multiple calls to plot within the for loop takes 0.95543 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple example:

```
x = 0:0.1:10; 
plot (x, sin(x), 'r') 
hold on

for i=1:size(x,2)
  if mod(i,5) == 0
    plot(x(i), sin(x(i)), 'b*'); 
    pause(0.2);
  endif
end
title('FINISHED')
```